# All ARIMA Processes unit root?

Tags: arima, unit-root

My question is are all ARIMA processes also unit root processes? My guess is yes because $\{X_t\}$ is ARIMA(p, d, q) if

$(1-B)^dX_t = a(B)\epsilon_t$

is stationary ARMA(p, q).

The characteristic function for $(1-B)^dX_t = a(B)\epsilon_t$ is $(1-B)^d$, which clearly is unit root.

Also, I suppose not all unit root processes are ARIMA? Is there a good counterexample?

My third and final question is are all FARIMA processes stationary? My guess is not because it really depends on the roots of the characteristic equation. I am asking this because I see FARIMA often used as an example for a "stationary long memory" process.

Comment: @Taylor Why not? For example, if $d=1$ then $(1-B)^dX_t = a(B)\epsilon_t \Rightarrow X_t = X_{t-1} + a(B)\epsilon_t$.

Comment: counterexample $X_t = .9X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + .8 \epsilon_{t-1}$

Comment: @ Student Also, you mean characteristic equation or characteristic polynomial. Characteristic function is somethign else.

Comment: also, $(1-B)^dX_t = a(B)\epsilon_t$ is IMA(d,q) or ARMA(1,q), but it is not ARIMA(p,d,q) if $p \ne 0$.

Comment: @Taylor Yep I meant characteristic equation. My apologies if that was confusing. Just to make sure we are on the same page, would you agree that $X_t = X_{t-1} + \epsilon$ is ARIMA(1, 1, 0)?

Comment: no, you can't "double-count" it's lag-1 dependence

Comment: @Taylor Ok I agree that $X_t = X_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$ is ARIMA(0, 1, 0).  It is true that $(1-B)^dX_t = a(B)\epsilon_t$ is ARIMA(0, d, q) if $Y_t = a(B)\epsilon_t$ is stationary ARMA(0, q) where $Y_t = (1-B)^dX_t$ right?

Comment: yes, and you could change the if to an iff.

Comment: @Taylor So all ARIMA processes have p=0?

Comment: what? no, they don't.

Comment: @Taylor What would be an example of an ARIMA(1,1,0) model?

Comment: @Taylor Ok so something like $y_t - y_{t-1} = a_1(y_{t-1} - y_{t-2}) + \epsilon_t$ is ARIMA(1, 1, 0). What is the general rule for ARIMA models then? For example, is $y_t - y_{t-1} = a_1(y_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t$ ARIMA?

Comment: Regarding FARIMA (or ARFIMA), stationarity depends on the order of integration. If I remember correctly, when the order is up to 0.5, it is stationary, when above, then nonstationary. But you may double-check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_t$ is ARIMA(p,d,0) with $p,d > 0$, then yes, it is also a unit root process. If your AR model with a unit root is 
$$
\Phi_1(B)X_t = \epsilon_t,
$$
then you can factor your characteristic polynomial
$$
\Phi_1(B) = \Phi_2(B)(1-B)^d.
$$
That's what a unit root is. It's just polynomials.

The reason this is more confusing than it should be is because when we say "Let $X_t$ be ARIMA", we're not saying what the restrictions on p,d and q are, and we're not saying what the restrictions on the coefficients are.